# Number of non-equal pairs in a binary sequence if strategy alternates.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Taken from [Codeforces contest 159 Div 2 Problem B](https://codeforces.com/contest/257/problem/B)

As I understand it, the problem is as follows.

We have $n$ red cubes and $m$ blue cubes.
Two players take turns appending a cube to the end of a sequence $s$.
The first player aims to maximize the number of pairs $(s_i, s_{i+1}):s_i = s_{i+1}$. 
While the second player aims to maximize the number of pairs $(s_i, s_{i+1}):s_i \neq s_{i+1}$.

We are interested in how successful each player is if they both play optimally. For example
if $n=3, m=1$. Then $s=[B,R,R,R]$ and the first player's score is $2$ while the second player's score is $1$.

The answer is that player 2's score is $\min(n,m)$. Of course player 2's score is the remaining pairs.

I understand that the total number of pairs is $n + m - 1$ but for some reason I can't make the intuitive leap that if player 1 acts optimally then player 2 will only ever get $\min(n,m)$ pairs of differing color.

My initial thought was that player 1 wants to maximize the difference between n and m while player 2 wants to do the opposite but that is incorrect.

What am I missing here? Is there some reading I can do to grasps these types of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let blue be the minority color.  If there is an odd number of blue cubes, Player $1$ should start with blue, as you have in your $n=3,m=1$ example.  Then if each player follows a greedy strategy the string will go $BRRBBRRBBRR$ until the blues run out, then all the rest will be red.  Every blue has exactly one red next to it because all except the first are in pairs.  If there is an even number of blue cubes, player $1$ should start with red and the string will go $RBBRRBBRRBB$ until the blues run out and again every blue cube has exactly one red next to it.  Player $2$ then gets one point per blue cube.

If there is the same even number of red and blue cubes the string will start and end with single cubes of the same color with pairs alternating in the middle.  Again every cube in a pair will have one neighbor that matches and one that does not, so player $2$ will get the number of cubes of one color.  If there is the same odd number of cubes there will be an odd cube at each end of different colors.  Again each cube of one color is next to exactly one cube of the other color.  We conclude that Player $2$ gets the number of blue cubes as long as there are that many or more red ones.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_2(n,m)$ be the number of points player 2 can make in the remaining game when having $n$ and $m$ cubes of each colour available and the last cube (placed by player 1) is of the $n$-colour.

One of the $m$ second colour cubes can be second in a pair of consecutive different colour cubes at most $\min\{m,n+1\}$ times, similarly one of the $n$ first colour cubes can be that at most $\min\{n,m\}$ times. We conclude
$$\tag1f_2(n,m)\le \min\{m,n+1\}+\min\{n,m\}. $$
In particular, $f_2(n,0)\le0$,  $f_2(0,m)\le 1$ and in fact we readily see that a greedy approach for player 2 indeed leads to 
 $f_2(n,0)=0$ and $f_2(0,m)=1$ (if $m\ge1$).
Likewise, $f_2(n,1)=2$ if $n\ge1$, $f_2(1,2)=2$ (stricter that $(1)$ because player 1 can intervene in an obvious manner), and $f_2(1,m)=3$ if $m\ge3$.

If $n,m\ge2$ and player 2 makes a greedy move next, player 1 can reply greedily leading to $1+f_2(m-2,n)$ points for player 2, or with a different reply by player 1, we end up with $2+f_2(n-1,m-1)$ points. So with greedy play at the first move, player 2 can enforce
$$\tag2\min\{1+f_2(m-2,n),2+f_2(n-1,m-1)\} $$
points. Similarly, if player 2 starts with the non-greedy move, they can enforce
$$\tag3\min\{f_2(n-2,m),1+f_2(m-1,n-1)\}.$$
So ultimately, $f_2(n,m)$ will be the max of $(2)$ and $(3)$.

**Claim.** $f_2(n,m)=g(\lceil\frac n2\rceil,\lceil\frac m2\rceil)$ where 
$$g(n,m)=\begin{cases}2m&n\ge m\\2n+1&n<m.\end{cases} $$

*Proof.* The claim matches our findings for he cases with $n\le 1$ or $m\le 1$. The rest follows by induction using $(2)$ and $(3)$ (and noting that the latter never contributes - i.e., the greedy strategy is optimal for player 2). $\square$

Finally, the result for the first player will be $$n+m-1-\min\{f_2(n-1,m),f_2(m-1,n)\}.$$
By going through all cases, this turns out to be
$$\max\{n,m\}-(\min\{n,m\}\bmod 2). $$
Accordingly, player2 gets $n+m-1$ minus this, i.e., 
$$\min\{n,m\}+(\min\{n,m\}\bmod 2)-1. $$